# undefined method `default_image' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, undefined

> ```
> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `default_image' for nil:NilClass):
>     409:
>     410: <!-- Image -->
>     411: <div class="image">
>     412:   <% if @product.default_image %>
>     413:
>     414:     <a href="#" class="main"><%= image_tag @product.default_image.path, :weight => '262px',:height => '197px'%></a>
>     415:   <% end %>
> ```

model:

```
# Return attachment for the default_image role
#
# @return [String]
def default_image
  self.attachments.for("default_image")
end

# Set attachment for the default_image role
def default_image_file=(file)
  self.attachments.build(file: file, role: 'default_image')
end
```

controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = Shoppe::Product.root.ordered.includes(:product_categories, :variants)
    @products = @products.group_by(&:product_category)
    @product = Shoppe::Product.root.find_by_permalink(params[:permalink])
    @order = Shoppe::Order.find(current_order.id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@product = Shoppe::Product.root.find_by_permalink(params[:permalink])` returns nil.  So when you try to call `default_image` on it then it breaks.

You could check it exists via

```
<% if @product && @product.default_image %>
  <a href="#" class="main"><%= image_tag @product.default_image.path, :weight => '262px',:height => '197px'%></a>
<% end %>
```

Or if you wanted to raise an error if it doesn't exist you can use the bang method of the dynamic finder.

```
@product = Shoppe::Product.root.find_by_permalink!(params[:permalink])
```

Also that's the older syntax for dynamic finders.  The new one is

```
@product = Shoppe::Product.root.find_by!(permalink: params[:permalink])
```